# Движок NoSql для Vusial Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nosql

Требуется СУБД или работа с файлами-таблицами напрямую (а ля dbf как раньше было).

Нечто очень простое, оффлай (то есть работа с файлом напрямую или через драйвер под win).
Нужен GUI-менеджер для редактирования/создания таблиц (Когда-то была Visual Fox Pro, но даже такой сложности не обязательно).

Рассматривал LiteDB, но там нет менеджера СУБД, всё кодить нужно. mongodb вроде с серверной частью.

У меня предполагается работа с очень ограниченным и одинаковым набором данных. Единственное, файлы-таблицы могут быть больше 4 Гб.

По идее, подходит источник данных ODBC, но GUI менеджера не нашёл и не знаю насколько годная вещь в 2021 году.

Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: `LiteDB, но там нет менеджера СУБД` - есть, любой по запросу в гугле `LiteDB Viewer` (например [этот](https://github.com/julianpaulozzi/LiteDbExplorer) или [этот](https://github.com/falahati/LiteDBViewer)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, побоялся что-то со стороны юзать...

Comment: Ну вы программист, смотрите исходный код, смотрите что делает программа, смотрите репутацию авторов, их рейтинг и так далее, изучайте вопрос. Сейчас весь интернет живет на опен соурсе. Вон на официальном [GitHub](https://github.com/mbdavid/litedb) есть [утилита от авторов](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB.Studio) даже.